# How to store and extract Opencv keypoints/ Descriptor in external file using python

Tags: python, opencv, sift

Im Working on SIFT based search engine using python. I can extract keypoints and descriptor but I need a way to store them plus extract them. There are lots of images too.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look what other people do in Python.
Some of them store keypoints, descriptors in .h5py or .h5 files
[Others](https://github.com/mihaidusmanu/d2-net) [use](https://github.com/naver/r2d2) .npz, .nvm or .mat.
I think these are standard formats and you could efficiently store SIFT features in these containers.

Comment: I tried to find but I wasn't able to find any reliable method. If you have any please post it here, it'll great help

Comment: You can find an example [here](https://github.com/mihaidusmanu/d2-net/blob/master/extract_features.py) which I already mentioned. Keypoint storage starts at line 131. It should not be too difficult to adapt to SIFT features.